# How to show a custom bar on top of the screen after scrolling

Tags: android

I have an app with a linear vertical layout that has an image on top with some parameters overlaid on it (for example: a resturant image will have parameters like rating, ambience etc.). When user scrolls down and when the image gets hidden, I want to add a small panel on top with thumbnail of the image and some of the details that were earlier overlaid on the image.
When scrolled on top, the panel will get hidden and bigger image in the imageView will again appear with overlaid data.

How do I achieve this?
[Image showing how it should look after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttatN.png)

Comment: Use a custom behaviour via `coordinator layout`

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful.